# How to print plugin vars in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, var

How can I print plugin variables in declarative pipeline?
I am trying to print vars for "Bitbucket Branch Source plugin" as mention [here](https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/931201025/Environment+variables+for+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+plugin)!. I am using multibranch pipeline and sh 'printenv' - it doesn't print vars of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it should give you the environment variables. Are you sure it's enabled on your job?